# onAction="#ClickedClickMe" not working in JavaFX FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

Good Morning! I have just started ramping up on Java FX and Java FX FXML. I'm using Scene Builder to build the GUI and Netbeans to code the remaining Java FX program.

The issue I'm facing is in FXML File. The Netbeans editor shows an error on the following code in .fxml file for onAction Event.

**Error that I see in fxml file**:
Controller is NOT defined on root component.

**Exception Text:**

> Executing sample1.jar using platform C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre/bin/java Exception in Application start
>   method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
>   file:/C:/Users/hmitty/Documents/NetBeansProjects/sample1/dist/run1317822864/sample1.jar!/sample1/FXMLDocument.fxml:21
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:557)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:599)
>     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)   at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)     at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)     at
>   sample1.Sample1.start(Sample1.java:22)    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     ... 1 more Exception running application sample1.Sample1 Picked up
>   _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true Java Result: 1

If I create a sample project using Netbeans, it uses AnchorPane and everything seems to be fine. However if I remove AnchorPane and add any other pane and the Button, the onAction Event doesn't work!

I'm a beginner in this language, hence any help/guidance is highly appreciated!

Note: I did my homework for close to half a day in browsing all available solutions as far as I can on StackOverFlow.

The closest I got is this, so any help will definitely move things for me!
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091582

All the code is pasted below. Let me know if anything else is required!

**FXML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.event.ActionEvent?>

<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#ClickedClickMe" text="Click Me!" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
      <Label fx:id="label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

**Sample1.java**

```
package sample1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Sample1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sample1;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;

    @FXML
    private void ClickedClickMe(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Clicked Try me!!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Set controller in fxml file**

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample1.FXMLDocumentController" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111">
```

Comment: When I continued browsing for solution after posting this question, found this link.

http://javafxforbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/02/solved-error-controller-is-not-defined.html

Your answer is exactly the same. Thanks! Problem solved now.